# Updating Database Using Dapper

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

I don't know if is this is possible in [dapper](/questions/tagged/dapper).
Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}

    public int UpdateStudent(Student student)
    {
        string sql="Update Student set FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName where Id=@Id";
        Dapper.Execute(sql, student)
    }
}
```

Now, on the calling code, I will have something like this:

```
Student student=new Student();
student.Id=1;
student.FirstName="abc";
student.UpdateStudent(student);
```

Now, if we are going to update the `Student` and only provide `Id` and `FirstName`, it will throw an error that I will also need to provide the `LastName`. I am looking for a solution that can be use that even if if I do not specify the `Student.LastName`, it will still do the update and since I don't specify the `LastName`, the `Student.LastName` will remain the same.

Comment: No idea what your question is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my question to make it clear for everyone.

Comment: You will need to use an IF statement

Comment: Dapper is a simple object mapper for .Net and does not provide what you want. You must use EntityFramework OR/M.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad I've no idea what you mean by that statement -- Drapper works as well as anything for this -- you just have to the write the logic yourself to build the update.

Comment: @Hogan you are right, but as you said you should provide it by yourself. Just think about this question: "Does Dapper generate update statement? does it track object changes?".

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad -- it is super easy to write a generic routine that loops over the fields of the object and generates the update statement.  Maybe 10 lines at most.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad -- I do it here to create a parameter list in an even more scaled down version of a Drapper like framework : https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/b7f5c5e8dde61ae3cd6f

Comment: @Hogan As you said it is super easy and I agree with that. But when there is a robust, reliable OR/M which does the job much much better than my code why I should do that.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad - code loses risk the more it is used... I've run that gist against millions of rows of data in production systems... so I'm confident it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a quick and dirty:

> I did not compile or test this so it might have a typo

```
public static void UpdateFromItem(string tableName, object updatevalues, object selectorvalue)
  {
    string updateStr=new String();
    string whereStr=new String();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in updatevalues.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.GetValue(parms, null) != null)
          updateStr.AppendFormat(" %s=%s",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(parms, null));
    }

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in selectorvalues.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.GetValue(parms, null) != null)
          updateStr.AppendFormat(" %s=%s",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(parms, null));
    }


    string sqlStmt=string.Format(@"UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s",tableName, updateStr,wherreStr);

    Drapper.Execute(sqlStmt);
  }
```

Call it like this

```
  UpdateFromItem("Student", new { FirstName : "abc"}, new { Id : 1 });
```

I made a generic solution above, you could also "know" about the id field for student object specifically then a solution like this would work:

```
  public static void UpdateStudent(Student inobj)
  {
    string updateStr=new String();
    string whereStr=string.Format(@"Id=%s",inobj.Id);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in inobj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if ((prop.GetValue(parms, null) != null) && (prop.Name != 'Id'))
          updateStr.AppendFormat(" %s=%s",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(parms, null));
    }

    string sqlStmt=string.Format(@"UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s",tableName, updateStr,wherreStr);

    Drapper.Execute(sqlStmt);
  }
```

People will point out that this is has injection risk.  That can be solved by composing a parameter list  -- but I think you get the idea.  Basically you need a loop.

---

---

This isn't hard you will need an if statement, something like this:

```
if (student.lastName.IsNullOrEmpty())
  Dapper.Execute("Update Student set FirstName=@FirstName where Id=@Id", student);
else
  Dapper.Execute("Update Student set FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName where Id=@Id", student);
```

Comment: yeah that will do but since i have a large number of column in my database, that will be a lot more work for me :D

Comment: @DikongPrigm you might want to consider an "automatic" routine that looks at the object fields and changes the update statement based on its contents.  Do you need me to show you how to do that?

Comment: I would love to have an example.

Comment: @DikongPrigm ok give me a few minutes

Comment: Thanks, ill try to play around with it.